# Move vector layer based on YX (Meters)

Tags: qgis, gdal, translation

I need to move a vector layer XY (Meters) how can I do that used the gdal? I found something for rasters, but I want something for a Vector layer from osgeo import gdal.

Answer (score 4):

From the Processing toolbox there's a ["Translate"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#translate) tool, which shifts vector geometries by a set amount in the x/y directions.